# Как сохранить данные при выключении бота? (Локализация бота)

Tags: python, база-данных, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def lang(ctx, mean):
    if mean == 'ru':
        for filename in os.listdir('./cog_ru'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                bot.load_extension(f'cog_ru.{filename[:-3]}')
        Russian = discord.Embed(title='Успех!', description='Язык изменён на Русский', color=0x00ff00)
        Russian.set_footer(text='MBK 2023, Все права защищены!')      
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=Russian)
    else:
        for filename in os.listdir('./cog_en'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                bot.load_extension(f'cog_en.{filename[:-3]}')
        English = discord.Embed(title='Success!', description='language changed to English', color=0x00ff00)
        English.set_footer(text='MBK 2023, all rights reserved!')
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=English)
```

У меня есть такой код, но при выключении бота эти данные удаляются и приходится заново прописывать команду, как добавить эту команду в базу данных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> У меня есть такой код, но при выключении бота эти данные удаляются и
> приходится заново прописывать команду.

*Происходит это из-за того, что настройка хранится в оперативной памяти. Это, логично.*

> Как добавить эту команду в базу данных?

Это зависит от того какую **СУБД** вы собираетесь использовать.

Если бот приватный - вы можете использовать текстовой формат обмена данными (например **Json**) или базу данных **SQLite**, которую обычно применяют для служебного пользования, например, в десктопных приложениях.

Для масштабируемых решений, если данные для локализации нужно запоминать для множества серверов, можно использовать мощные серверные системы, по типу **MySQL** (**SQL**) или если хотите что-то из серии **NoSQL** - это уже по обстоятельствам.

Comment: думаю можно использовать SQLite, поможете добавить его в команду?

Comment: Не помогу - вы проектируете бота.